# how to use same rabbitmq queue in different java microservice

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am new here for rabbitmq,my question is how can we use same queue for different consumer or different microservices. In my project i have centralise rabbitmq and created two different spring boot applications.In that i am calling one service in first application in that its creating one queue in rabbitmq and also receiving message from that queue but in my second application its not receiving that message from queue. Can anybuddy tell me how can i call or use one queue in two different applications.

here is my code for first application.
Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidate-corpus/")

public class RabbitMQWebController {

@Autowired
RabbitMQSender rabbitMQSender;

@Autowired
RabbitMQReceiver rabbitMQReceiver;

@GetMapping(value = "/updater")
public String producer(@RequestParam("candName") String 
 candName,@RequestParam("candId") String candId) {

    Candidate candidate=new Candidate();
    candidate.setCandId(candId);
    candidate.setCandName(candName);
    rabbitMQSender.send(candidate);
    //rabbitMQReceiver.recievedMessage(emp);

    return "Message sent to the RabbitMQ Corpus Successfully";
 }
```

Config file:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.queue}")
String queueName;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.exchange}")
String exchange;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.routing-key}")
private String routingkey;

@Bean
Queue candidateUpdater1() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
FanoutExchange xyz() {
    return new FanoutExchange(exchange);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, FanoutExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory 
connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new 
 RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public RabbitMQReceiver receiver() { return new RabbitMQReceiver();}

}
```

RabbitMqSender.java

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQSender {

@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.exchange}")
private String exchange;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.routing-key}")
private String routingkey;

public void send(Candidate cand) {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, cand);
    System.out.println("exchange kye"+exchange);
    System.out.println("routing key"+routingkey);
    System.out.println("cand obj. "+cand);

}
}
```

RabbitMq Receiver:

```
public class RabbitMQReceiver {

@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.exchange}")
private String exchange;

@Value("${rabbitmqqueuelist.routing-key}")
private String routingkey;

@RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmqqueuelist.queue}")
public void recievedMessage(Candidate obj) {

  // Object obj1 = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();

    System.out.println("-----------"+obj.toString());
    System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + obj.getCandName());
    System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + obj.getCandId());
 }
}
```

here is application.yml file

```
  rabbitmq:
  host: localhost
  port: 15672
  username: guest
  password: guest

 rabbitmqqueuelist.exchange: xyz
 rabbitmqqueuelist.routing-key: candidateUpdater
 rabbitmqqueuelist.queue: candidateUpdater1
```

so above is my first application code.in that i am sending and receiving the data from queue but while i am running my second application in that its not receiving.Can anyone guide me how can i achieve that.

Note:for second application i have used same code which given above.

I already go through the official website but not able to understand, thats why i asked here

Thank you.

Comment: Check RabbitMQ admin UI - how many consumers do you see there for your queue? Does it correspond the number of running instances?

Comment: yes its showing two but not receiving data in 2nd application

Comment: and thanks for reply

Comment: Maybe your first application manages to process all messages? Add a pause in receiver code.

Comment: actually i want to receive message from queue in both application,if i change in first appln then it will also received to the 2nd application

Comment: Just to make it clear: do you want to deliver the same message to each consumer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168816/discussion-between-zaif-warm-and-lexicore).

Comment: yes
i want to deliver the same message to each consumer

Comment: I already go through the official website but not able to understand, thats why i asked here

Comment: Read the question I've linked as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160585/rabbitmq-same-message-to-each-consumer